# Determine magnetic force at a pole?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

So my friend took a physics exam and one of the questions on it has me confused (It has been a long time since I have taken physics). The question was worded very badly (I had to translate from Spanish to English) and had incorrect formatting... but from what I can gather, the question asked:

There are 2 isolated south poles, separated by $40\ cm$ in air and have $40\ Am$ intensity at each pole. A third South Pole, which has $30\ Am$, is located $30\ cm$ below poles $1$ and $2$, as shown in the diagram below. Determine the magnetic force exerted at pole one?

How do I calculate this?

I was thinking of using the formula $$F= \frac{u q_1 q_2}{ 4\pi r^2}$$

but I'm not sure if this is correct? Any suggestions as to how I would answer this question?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Was your friend taught that isolated magnetic poles exist? I was taught that they don’t.

Comment: Is the $u$ supposed to be $\mu_0$?

Comment: Related: [What would be the force constant for magnetic monopoles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121497/what-would-be-the-force-constant-for-magnetic-monopoles)

Comment: I made the assumption that   is the magnetic permeability of air. The question was written so poorly. And in Spanish (which isn't my native tongue), so there may have been a slight mistranslation.